# Discount are showing in decimal numbers

Tags: magento-1.9, price, jquery

please visit this  [configurable product](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship-2.html)

you can see **color : "choose an option "**

please change to **"grey"** , discounts are displaying in decimal numbers.

once you refresh the page, its working fine.

we are using following code :

```
var discountAmount = ((price - finalPrice) / price) * 100;
jQuery('.you_save_price').text(discountAmount + '%');
```

[image]

Comment: var num = 5.56789; var n = num.toFixed(2); result = 5.57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Math.round()`  function

`jQuery('.you_save_price').text(Math.round(discountAmount) + '%');`

if you want to show in decimal point you can use `toFixed`

`jQuery('.you_save_price').text(discountAmount.toFixed(2) + '%');`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fix this with JS you could use:

To **round down**

```
Math.floor()
```

To **round up**

```
Math.ceil()
```

Or just **round to the nearest integer**

```
Math.round()
```

Keep in mind that Math.floor() will increase numerical value when number is negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for support, its a very usefull information.....